# Issue creating graph database using apache AGE extension

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I'm trying to create a graph database from an existing relational database. So a little background information is that I have a tbale with product numbers and serial numbers and I want a graph database that illustrates their relations. I have a tree like structure in the product numbers, that's why I want to make a graph database with the apache AGE.

I have managed to run the command:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.create_graph('part_numbers_graph');
```

But when I run:

```
INSERT INTO part_numbers_graph
    SELECT agtype(format('{"id": %L, "label": "SSN", "properties": {"name": %L}}', SSN, SSN)::jsonb)
    FROM serial_table;
```

I get the following error:

```
relation "part_numbers_graph" does not exist
```

I have ran the command:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_graph;
```

I can see that the graph is there.

```
 graphid |        name        |     namespace
---------+--------------------+--------------------
32924 | part_numbers_graph | part_numbers_graph
```

I have succesfully been able to run both

```
CREATE EXTENSION age;
```

and

```
LOAD 'age';
```

When I run

```
pg_config
```

I can see that I have installed
VERSION = PostgreSQL 12.14 (Ubuntu 12.14-1.pgdg22.04+1)

Answer (score 0):

`part_numbers_graph` is not a regular Postgres table, but a graph table which stores data in the form of vertices and edges and requires data to be inserted using `cypher` queries.
For more information above `cypher` queries, see the official Apache AGE [documentation](https://age.apache.org/age-manual/master/intro/cypher.html).

For your particular example, a cypher query would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('part_numbers_graph', $$
CREATE (n:SSN {id: 'SSN' , name: 'SSN' }) 
$$) as (a agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert values into a graph you should use the cypher function.
For example in your case the query will look something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('part_numbers_graph', $$ 
CREATE (u:SSN {"id": "<insert_id>", "name": "<insert_name>""})
RETURN u $$) AS (u agtype);
```

With this query you create a node that has `SSN` label and has 2 property fields `id` and `name`. Age has its own way to create `id's` though so maybe you don't have to actually hard code your own `id` in the query and just let age keep track of the `id's` of the different nodes and edges.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have successfully created the graph, the error stating "relation 'part_number_graph' does not exist suggest that it is not present in the current scchema. What I suggest is that you should create the above-mentioned table before insert query:
Creating a table:

```
    CREATE TABLE part_numbers_graph (
  id bigserial primary key,
  label text,
  properties jsonb
);
```

Now, use the insert query:

```
INSERT INTO part_numbers_graph
SELECT agtype(format('{"id": %L, "label": "SSN", "properties": {"name": %L}}', SSN, SSN)::jsonb)
FROM serial_table;
```

Hope it helped!

Comment: I tried this now, but when doing the second querie i get the error:

ERROR:  function agtype(jsonb) does not exist
LINE 2: SELECT agtype(format('{"id": %L, "label": "SSN", "properties...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to first check if the relational table exists and that you are referencing it correctly as the error shows that it does not exist. The backslash command `\dt` can be used to check the existing list of relations you have.

Adding to the solutions already suggested here, you can also use prepared statements or pgsql functions to import data from a table into a graph, which you can read more about [here](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/50#issuecomment-819722171)

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert in the `part_numbers_graph` as inserting in a normal postgres table instead you should use the cypher function that is offered by the AGE extension.

So your query should be modified as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('part_numbers_graph', $$
MERGE (u:SSN {id: 'your_id' , name: 'your_name' }) 
$$) as (res agtype);
```

So this query will create a new vertex with label `SSN` and with two properties : `id` and `name`.

If the vertex already exists the vertex will be updated instead of creating new one because here I am using `MERGE`.

If you want to create a new vertex every time even if it is a duplicate you can use `CREATE`.

Answer (score 0):

1.`CREATE EXTENSION age';`

2.`LOAD 'age';`

3. `SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_graph;`
4. 

```
     CREATE TABLE part_numbers_graph (
  id bigserial primary key,
  label text,
  properties jsonb
);
```

5. `SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_graph;`
6. 

```
INSERT INTO part_numbers_graph
SELECT agtype(format('{"id": %L, "label": "SSN", "properties": {"name": %L}}', SSN, SSN)::jsonb)
FROM serial_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

The part_numbers_graph isn't a typical Postgres table. Instead, it's a graph table that holds data as vertices and edges. You need to use special commands called 'cypher queries' to put data into it.

```
    SELECT * FROM cypher('part_numbers_graph', $$ 
    CREATE (u:SSN {"id": "<insert_id>", "name": "<insert_name>""})
    RETURN u $$) AS (u agtype);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with the naming of the graph. Generally, as best practice the schema name is prepended before the graph name so make sure you are using the correct naming scheme. Here's an example of how you could write the query:

```
INSERT INTO part_numbers_graph.part_numbers_graph
SELECT agtype(format('{"id": %L, "label": "SSN", "properties": {"name": %L}}', SSN, SSN)::jsonb)
FROM serial_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the cypher() function and write Cypher queries to define your graph structure.

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('part_numbers_graph', $$ 
CREATE (u:SSN {"id": 12345, "name": "John"})
RETURN u $$) AS (u agtype);
```

In this query, you are creating a node with the label "SSN" and two property fields: "id" and "name".

I hope this would help.